# UWP Manifest issue / restricted capability / inputForegroundObservation

Tags: windows-store-apps, uwp, windows-10-universal, keyboard-events

I'm trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35422422/access-raw-keyboard-input-in-universal-windows-app-iot) StackOverflow article, referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33981364/restricted-capabilities-on-uwp-apps) similar article on StackOverflow, and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations) from the UWP Windows Dev Center.

In my manifest XML, the `<Package>` tag was updated to include `xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"` and also `IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp wincap rescap"`.

My `<Capabilities>` section looks like this:

`<Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="inputForegroundObservation" />
  </Capabilities>`

And `<rescap:Capability` is underlined with error:

> "The element 'Capabilities'... has invalid child element...in...namespace.../windows10/restrictedcapabilities..."

(I snipped away much of the very long error message)

Any advice on how I can get the inputForegroundObservation Capability recognized?  VS Community 2015 sp3, Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform package installed.

Cheers,
Adam

Comment: It is just telling you that the restricted capability you are asking for is not declared in the schema.  A warning, not a fatal error.  That is not terribly surprising, the [MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations) point out that this "is highly restricted and subject to additional Store onboarding policy and review".  App submission has to be done specially and it takes up to 5 days longer to review your app.  I suspect that if it looks anything at all like a key logger then your submission is going to be rejected.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  Nothing nefarious; just a port of a very old C++ app that makes use of things like CTRL-A, C, J, X, Y, and Z - all of which seem to be handled outside the scope of the usual KeyDown event.  I could change this in the app, but would rather keep its character intact.  My test app still does not compile; gives a manifest validation error ("The app manifest XML must be valid") on the `<Package>` line.

Comment: There is nothing wrong  in your manifest. Perhaps your c ++ code asks for other capability. Could I touch your c++ code?

Comment: Hi Nico - can I send you a zip file with the project (and how can I do this)?  It's just a test project, to get the manifest and event handler working at a basic level, not the actual ported C++ code, which I'm developing separately for now.  Cheers, Adam

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Answer:

1. In the `<package>` tag, do not include `wincap` or `rescap` in `IgnorableNameSpaces`.
2. You do not need a corporate account to build the app successfully and without error.  I used the freely-downloadable Visual Studio Community 2015 fully updated as of 2017-03-03.
3. The `rescap:Capability Name=` will continue to be underlined in the package XML editor, but this does not mean you will have any build warnings or errors.
4. I put a comment in the [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations#special-and-restricted-capabilities) that says that `rescap` "must" be included in `IgnorableNameSpaces` - this was clearly throwing me off, and may well confuse others, also.
5. More information [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/f7e1f948-7be6-4d84-90eb-4de7e44b9928/uwpusing-restricted-capabilities-in-uwp-application?forum=wpdevelop&prof=required).

Hope this helps someone.

Cheers,

Answer (score 8):

For Visual Studio 2019. The order is also important. I was putting the `rescap:Capability` last and kept getting the build error. It works if it's first, before other capabilities

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations#restricted-capabilities

> All restricted capability elements must come before any CustomCapability and DeviceCapability elements under the Capabilities node in the package manifest.

For example

```
<Package  xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
  xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
  xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
  
...
    <Capabilities>
        <rescap:Capability Name="extendedBackgroundTaskTime"/>
        <Capability Name="internetClient" />
        <DeviceCapability Name="location"/>    
    </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

Comment: Excelent answer, bro!