# UWP app compile gets Validation error. C00CE014 in manifest

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

I get the following error when I try to build my UWP C# app after I added...

```
<rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" />
```

...the manifest to support broadFileSystemAccess.

Manifest ………………………………..
[image]

Popup error hovering mouse over horizontal blue squiggle line...
[image]

Error when Mouse hovering over ...

> "The element Capabilities in namespace 'http://schemas...has invalid
>   child element 'Capability' in namespace..."

Build error...

> Validation error. error C00CE014: App manifest validation error: The
>   app manifest must be valid as per schema: Line 40, Column 6, Reason:
>   Element
>   '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities}Capability'
>   is unexpected according to content model of parent element
>   '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10}Capabilities'.
>   Expecting:
>   {http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10}DeviceCapability.

Comment: [Don't ignore rescap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42356911/uwp-manifest-issue-restricted-capability-inputforegroundobservation).

Comment: What OS/SDK version is your UWP project targeting?

Comment: Stefan...  Window 10,k version 1803

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Hans Passant's suggestion, that fixed it.
specifically, I changed
                    IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap"

to
                    IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp"